# interrupted time series - data transformation - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, time-series

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and I have 2 questions if you can help.

I have 2 main tables:

```
Individual  Age  Gender
    1       66     1
    2       33     0
    3       72     1

Individual Appointment_Date Clinic
    1         10-12-2018      A 
    1         05-03-2019      A  
    1         31-08-2019      A 
    2         02-12-2018      A  
    2         16-03-2019      A  
    2         12-04-2019      A   
    2         16-05-2019      A 
    3         07-12-2018      B  
    3         12-05-2019      B 
    3         19-06-2019      B
```

I would like to run an interrupted time series analysis to understand the impact of an intervention on an outcome metric. I don't have this outcome metric, I need to estimate it, per week, using the Total_Appointments. I calculated Total_Appointments per individual across the total time, as per:

```
SELECT T1.Individual, COUNT(DISTINCT T2.Appointment_Date) AS [TOTAL_APPOINTMENTS]
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2
     ON T1.Individual = T2.Individual AND
        T2.APPOINTMENT_DATE > '2018-12-01' AND
        T2.APPOINTMENT_DATE < '2019-08-31'
```

**Question 1:** How can I estimate Total_Appointments per individual and *per week*? This is an intermediate step I need to perform, but I will end up with an outcome metric aggregated at clinic level.

Then, I'll also need to transform the other variables (Avg_Age, Avg_Gender) into regular time intervals such as:

```
Date_start   Date_end   Weeks_passed Clinic Outcome Avg_Age Avg_Gender Intervention_occurs
2018-12-02   2018-12-08       1         A      0.1      63      0.7           0
2018-12-02   2018-12-08       1         B      0.3      66      0.5           0
2018-12-02   2018-12-08       1         C      0.2      67      0.6           0
2018-12-09   2018-12-15       2         A      0.2      64      0.7           0
2018-12-09   2018-12-15       2         B      0.4      65      0.6           0
2018-12-09   2018-12-15       2         C      0.3      66      0.6           0
2018-12-16   2018-12-22       3         A      0.3      64      0.7           0
2018-12-16   2018-12-22       3         B      0.3      65      0.6           0
2018-12-16   2018-12-22       3         C      0.4      66      0.6           0
2018-12-23   2018-12-29       4         A      0.5      64      0.7           1
2018-12-23   2018-12-29       4         B      0.2      65      0.6           1
2018-12-23   2018-12-29       4         C      0.3      66      0.6           1
2018-12-30   2019-01-05       5         A      0.6      64      0.7           1
2018-12-30   2019-01-05       5         B      0.5      65      0.6           1
2018-12-30   2019-01-05       5         C      0.3      66      0.6           1
2019-01-06   2019-01-12       6         A      0.6      64      0.7           1
2019-01-06   2019-01-12       6         B      0.5      65      0.6           1
2019-01-06   2019-01-12       6         C      0.3      66      0.6           1
```

This study started on 2018-12-02 (Sunday) until 2019-08-31 (Saturday).

**Question 2:** Can you please advise on how to create such time-series table in SQL Server? I'll then import it into R and run the actual analysis there.

Answer (score 0):

For part 1 do it like this:

```
with t as (
select 1 individual, cast('20181210' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 1 individual, cast('20190305' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 1 individual, cast('20190831' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 2 individual, cast('20181202' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 2 individual, cast('20190316' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 2 individual, cast('20190412' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 2 individual, cast('20190516' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 3 individual, cast('20181207' as date) date, 'B' clinic union all
select 3 individual, cast('20190512' as date) date, 'B' clinic union all
select 3 individual, cast('20190619' as date) date, 'B' clinic 
), t1 as (
select *, cast(datepart(year, date) as char(4)) + cast(datepart(week, date) as char(2)) yearweek from t
)
select count(distinct date) cnt, individual, yearweek from t1 group by individual, yearweek
```

It creates a column `yearweek` that uses `datepart` in order to be able to group by week.

Now I can create the whole list with analytical functions instead of group by. There's a small problem because Microsoft Sql does not allow `count(distinct column) over (partition by ...)` - I'm using a workaround for that, using twice `dense_rank() over (...)`. I also added a start of week column and an end of week column.
As before, I'm using CTE's in order to first create the example data and then perform the wanted modifications
:

```
with t as (
select 1 individual, cast('20181210' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 1 individual, cast('20190305' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 1 individual, cast('20190831' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 2 individual, cast('20181202' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 2 individual, cast('20190316' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 2 individual, cast('20190412' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 2 individual, cast('20190516' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all
select 2 individual, cast('20190514' as date) date, 'A' clinic union all--new row to demonstrate count-distinct
select 3 individual, cast('20181207' as date) date, 'B' clinic union all
select 3 individual, cast('20190512' as date) date, 'B' clinic union all
select 3 individual, cast('20190619' as date) date, 'B' clinic 
), t1 as (
select *, cast(datepart(year, date) as char(4)) + cast(datepart(week, date) as char(2)) yearweek,
dateadd(day,   -((5 + DATEPART(dw, date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), date) start_of_week,
dateadd(day,  7-((5 + DATEPART(dw, date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), date) end_of_week
 from t
)
select dense_rank() over (partition by individual, yearweek order by date) + dense_rank() over (partition by individual, yearweek order by date desc) - 1 cnt_distinct, 
individual, yearweek, start_of_week, date, end_of_week
from t1 
order by yearweek, individual
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @casenonsensitive. I cannot follow your code though. what is the first date for example 20181210? also those 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3? I have thousands of individuals and hundreds of clinics, I would like to avoid specifying them individually if possible.

Comment: I added a more complex example with analytical functions. That might also be the way to go in order to create your time series. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Why do you start with 20181210? Should I use 20181202 instead as this is my initial day? Also why do we have 3 rows for select 1 and 5 rows for select 2 and 3 rows for select 3? My initial day for each clinic (1,2,3) should be the same. Sorry I am still trying to understand how your code will generate the table I need.

Comment: I just took the data from your example in order to demonstrate what how the query works. Of course you don't need it. Just use your table instead of whole `select 1 ... union all ... clinic` The thing is, I don't know how your tables/views are called on your database. I'd need that info in order to base the query on it.

Comment: of course, sorry I got it wrong - what I meant with that table is that we have different days for each individual who then attend different clinics. For these 3 individuals, I have those days but I have thousands of individuals and will have different ones coming from 02-12-2018 until 31-12-2019. I will have to create a general table first with the dates from 02-12-2018 until 31-12-2019 and then fill in the table with the correct individuals, if this makes sense?

Comment: Sorry - I realised now that you were replying to Question 1, and not Question 2. But still, I will not be able to specify all those clinics and dates for each individual (I have thousands), I will have to do it automatically, using GROUP BY or something like this, if this makes sense.

Comment: I'll need more info on your current table structure in order to propose something. What I wrote is an example of how to compute certain things.

Comment: sorry @casenonsensitive I should have provided more info. I found another way to do this. Thanks again for your help